# How to create a list of dictionary of users and list of folders for each user?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to create a dictionary of users which has list of folders in it.

```
users:
  name: user1
  folders:
    - user1-1
    - user1-2
  name: user2
  folders:
    - user2-1
    - user2-2
  name: userN
  folders:
    - userN-1
    - userN-2
```

I am trying to create this user dictionary list dynamically.

```
  - hosts: localhost   
    gather_facts: no   
    vars: 
      userCount: 5
      folderCount: 5
    tasks:
    - set_fact:
        user_lists: []        
    - name: creating list of users
      set_fact:
        user_lists: "{{ user_lists + [ 'user-' ~ item ] }}"
      with_sequence: count="{{userCount|int}}"
    - debug:
        var: user_lists      

     - set_fact:
        usersObj: []
        userDict: {}
 
    - name: add each user to dict
      set_fact:
         usersObj: "{{ usersObj + [userDict| combine({'name': item})] }}"
      with_items: "{{user_lists}}"

    - debug: var=usersObj
```

I have created 5 users in dictionary.  Now each user should have folder list created based on folderCount. How to resolve this? Can Jinja2 templates be used to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        user_lists: []
    - name: creating dictionary of users with lists of folders
      set_fact:
        user_lists: "{{ user_lists|combine({key: val}) }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end="{{ userCount }}"
      vars:
        folder_range: "{{ range(1, folderCount|int + 1)|list }}"
        key: "{{ 'user-' ~ item }}"
        val: "{{ [key]|
                 product(folder_range)|
                 map('join', '-')|
                 list }}"
        
    - debug:
        var: user_lists
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "user_lists": {
        "user-1": [
            "user-1-1",
            "user-1-2",
            "user-1-3",
            "user-1-4",
            "user-1-5"
        ],
        "user-2": [
            "user-2-1",
            "user-2-2",
            "user-2-3",
            "user-2-4",
            "user-2-5"
        ],
        "user-3": [
            "user-3-1",
            "user-3-2",
            "user-3-3",
            "user-3-4",
            "user-3-5"
        ],
        "user-4": [
            "user-4-1",
            "user-4-2",
            "user-4-3",
            "user-4-4",
            "user-4-5"
        ],
        "user-5": [
            "user-5-1",
            "user-5-2",
            "user-5-3",
            "user-5-4",
            "user-5-5"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a magic. What needs to be learnt to do this (Python or jinja2 )?